# Error: No such function: sqlcipher_export on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

I have installed SQLCipher via pod. but I am getting this error saying **No such function: sqlcipher_export**. I was using FMDB and for SQLCipher I am using the subspec of it i.e. FMDB/sqlcipher. I have added

```
#import <SQLCipher/sqlite3.h>
```

below is my code:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths; 
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyDB.db"]];

NSString *encryptDB = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB_enc.db"];

const char* sqlQ = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE '%@' AS MyDB_enc KEY 'test123';",encryptDB] UTF8String];

//sqlite3 *unencrypted_DB;

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    // Attach empty encrypted database to unencrypted database
    sqlite3_exec(database, sqlQ, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // export database
    sqlite3_exec(database, "SELECT sqlcipher_export('MyDB_enc');", NULL, NULL, NULL); //gives error

    // Detach encrypted database
    sqlite3_exec(database, "DETACH DATABASE MyDB_enc;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
else {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(NO, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB_enc.db"];
```

can anyone guide me on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experiencing this issue with POD installation but when I used the sqlite3.h file after compiling the binary it was working fine.